# iPhone SDK Simple Twitter Question

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'm just playing around with the iPhone SDK and wanted to make a really simple Twitter app but I'm not sure how to do this. I just need to fetch the last 5 updates from a user just through their username. For instance, if I type in "mashable", I should get mashable's 5 latest updates. How would I do that?

Thanks so much ahead of time!

Comment: If you are using Twitter make sure to use OAuth. They will cut off the Basic Authentication soon. Here is the countdown:
http://www.countdowntooauth.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194514/fetch-twitter-friend-list-after-authentification/10393978#10393978

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, MGTwitterEngine was the gold-standard free library to drop in for Twitter access via Objective-C.

http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

Comment: +1 I Agree. I used it for my app and it was spot on. It has also just been updated to support OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Did you support twitter login yet? If yes, you just need to call the Rest API using some [NSUrlConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)